# Dismiss view controller not executing when using material design dialogs in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dialog, material-design, dismissviewcontroller

I'm using material design dialog for my iOS app written with swift. Here is the brief documentation of material design dialogs: https://material.io/develop/ios/components/dialogs/

I have a dialog which has 1 action and in the completion block of the action, I want to dismiss the view controller and go back to the previous view controller. The problem is that dismissing the view controller doesn't work. All instructions which are written in the completion block, such as printing something, execute except for dismissing view controller.

Here is my code :

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let alertStr = "Alert"
        let alertController = MDCAlertController(title: "Error", message: alertStr)
        let action = MDCAlertAction(title:"GoBack") { (action) in
            self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
        alertController.addAction(action)
        self.present(alertController, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }
```

I'd appreciate if you could help me figure out the problem.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

1. The [`dismiss(animated:completion:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss) “Dismisses the view controller that was presented modally by the view controller.” It’s not intended to dismiss the the view controller referenced by `self`.

   Admittedly, `dismiss` will, “If you call this method on the presented view controller itself, UIKit asks the presenting view controller to handle the dismissal.” But you can’t rely upon that within the `UIAlertAction` for the button, because you don’t know when the dismissal of the `MDCAlertController` and when the action of the button is performed.
2. Are you sure you presented view controller and that it’s not, for example, having instead pushed on a navigation controller?
3. A good way of getting back to a prior view controller is an [unwind segue](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH15-SW8) (or see [TN2298](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2298/_index.html)). That eliminates all ambiguity about “push” v “present” and whether `dismiss` will dismiss a presented view controller and instead pass the message to the presenting view controller.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried to

```
  performSegue(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerSegue", sender: nil)
```

you need to select your viewController on the top-bar the yellow square(name is what you predefine)
right-click and drag to the next view controller ---> Present Modally 
then select the arrow and go to attributes inspector and name the identifier.

Comment: I haven't tried this and this probably would work but I don't wanna performSegue cause it creates a new instance of ViewController and I don't want that. I need to get back to the same instance of previous View controller.